# How to convert enum to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I am trying to use the Qt reflection for converting enum to QString.

Here is the part of code:

```
class ModelApple
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_ENUMS(AppleType)
public:
    enum AppleType {
      Big,
      Small
    }
}
```

And here is i trying to do:

```
convertEnumToQString(ModelApple::Big)
```

Return `"Big"`

Is this possible?
If you have any idea about `convertEnumToQString`, please share it

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to use [Q_ENUM](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) macro, which registers an enum type with the meta-object system.

```
enum AppleType {
  Big,
  Small
};
Q_ENUM(AppleType)
```

And now you can use the [QMetaEnum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaenum.html) class to access meta-data about an enumerator.

```
QMetaEnum metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<ModelApple::AppleType>();
qDebug() << metaEnum.valueToKey(ModelApple::Big);
```

---

Here is a generic template for such utility:

```
template<typename QEnum>
std::string QtEnumToString (const QEnum value)
{
  return std::string(QMetaEnum::fromType<QEnum>().valueToKey(value));
}
```

Comment: `QMetaEnum::fromType<T>` is available from Qt 5, it doesn't exist in Qt 4. You should add this remark. By the way, I don't recommend to use `QMetaEnum::key` since it take `index` as parameter, how come is he declared `enum AppleType { Big = 2, Small}`

Comment: From the docs, it looks like this is actually only available from Qt 5.5 thus I still need to use my method in the answer I gave (was about to update my code but have to use Qt 5.4 for now).

Comment: 'keyToValue()' can do the other way around: get the enum value from the string!

Comment: I got this: undefined reference to MyClass::staticMetaObject . I copied the example from official page of Q_ENUM .

Answer (score 44):

Much more elegant way found (Qt 5.9), just one single line, with the help of mighty QVariant.

turns enum into string:

```
QString theBig = QVariant::fromValue(ModelApple::Big).toString();
```

Perhaps you don't need QMetaEnum anymore.

Sample code here:

ModelApple (no need to claim Q_DECLARE_METATYE)

```
class ModelApple : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum AppleType {
      Big,
      Small
    };
    Q_ENUM(AppleType)
    explicit ModelApple(QObject *parent = nullptr);
};
```

And I create a widget application, calling QVaraint function there :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <modelapple.h>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString s = QVariant::fromValue(ModelApple::Big).toString();
    qDebug() << s;

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

You can see that i try to output the string on console , which really did:
[image]

And sorry for reverse casting , i tried successfully in some project , but some how this time i met compiling error. So i decide to remove it from my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering, looks like the method needs to add  `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ModelApple::AppleType)`, and even added make it compiled successful, the result is an empty string. Could you please post the example code for this?

Comment: For anyone struggling with this solution: you need Q_OBJECT and Q_ENUM. Also your enum has to be public.

Comment: @Cheesi you don't need `Q_OBJECT`: `Q_GADGET` is sufficient for this (unless you are really making a `QObject`).

Answer (score 9):

The following should get you going:

```
QString convertEnumToQString(ModelApple::AppleType type) {
    const QMetaObject metaObject = ModelApple::staticMetaObject;
    int enumIndex = metaObject.indexOfEnumerator("AppleType");
    if(enumIndex == -1) {
        /* The enum does not contain the specified enum */
        return "";
    }
    QMetaEnum en = metaObject.enumerator(enumIndex);
    return QString(en.valueToKey(type));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you join the declaration of `enumString` and `enumString = en.valueToKey(type);` it will call only 1 constructor instead of 1 constructor and 1 `operator =`. Also, we can eliminate the check with `-1` since we can sure that that enum is existed.

Comment: So i have to specify the enumerator "AppleType" ?

Comment: @Danh Yes you can do that. My actual code is a template function that takes in the enum name and the enum value to return the string. I modified it to answer the question. My usage is `string = convertEnumToQString<ModelApple>("AppleType", ModelApple::Big);` so I need to check for a valid enum and assert if not valid for debugging. Also I assert before the return thus the reason for first assigning and then returning (purely for debugging).

Comment: I get the the point for the template. Regarding the declaration, assign, and return, I still think that we shouldn't take an extra step,

Comment: @user3308570 Unfortunately yes unless you have Qt 5.5 (then you can use the other answer) that is why I suggest adding the check for in case you decide to change the name of the enum in future.

Comment: Okay,unfortunately  i am using Qt 5.3.
 Thanks guys.

Answer (score 9):

For the global Enum declaring use this in any header file:

```
namespace YourNamespace {

Q_NAMESPACE

enum YourEnum: int {

    EnumValue1,
    EnumValue2
};
Q_ENUM_NS(YourEnum)

}
```

and this where you want to get Enum description:

```
QMetaEnum metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<YourEnum>();
qDebug() << "Enum description: " << metaEnum.name() << "::" << metaEnum.valueToKey(YourEnum::EnumValue2);
```

Comment: I had tried to get this to work numerous times over the years, and recently I tried your solution, and was successful!  The trick was wrapping my "global" enum (ie: not contained within a class) inside a namespace.  Thanks!

Comment: Such a helpful answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
QString convertEnumToQString(ModelApple::AppleType type)
{
    const QMetaObject &mo = ModelApple::staticMetaObject;
    int index = mo.indexOfEnumerator("AppleType");
    QMetaEnum metaEnum = mo.enumerator(index);
    return metaEnum.valueToKey(type);
}
```

**UPDATED:** For Qt 5.5, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34282031/4115625)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and this is how i solved it. This is especially for **Qt 4.8**

```
QString string = enumToString(ModelApple::Big);

QString ModelApple::enumToString(AppleType apple)
{
    int index = metaObject()->indexOfEnumerator("AppleType");
    QMetaEnum metaEnum = metaObject()->enumerator(index);
    return metaEnum.valueToKey(apple);
}
```