# Is there a way to use QMetaEnum with Q_ENUMS belonging to non Q_OBJECT or Q_GADGET class?

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

For example I have the following class:

```
namespace someName
{
    class someClass
    {
        Q_ENUMS(ESomeEnum)

        public:
        enum ESomeEnum {ENUM_A, ENUM_B, ENUM_C};

        // ... some other things ..
    }
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(someName::someClass)
```

Is there a way to use QMetaEnum::valueToKey or QMetaEnum::keyToValue ?

Tried the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34282031/6434754) but got the following error:

> ```
> error: static assertion failed: QMetaEnum::fromType only works with enums declared as Q_ENUM or Q_FLAG
> #define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
> ```

I can employ X-Macros to get my desired output but it would also be nice to learn  more tricks in Qt.

Comment: You are using `Q_ENUMS`, I think you have to use `Q_ENUM` in this case.

Comment: i am maintaining code written in this manner and changing Q_ENUMS to Q_ENUM would flag unnecessary "panic" to the project manager as this affects a lot of files.

Comment: As of right now, the accepted answer should be different. @DrumM is correct, since Qt 5.8 you could use `Q_NAMESPACE` + `Q_ENUM_NS` combo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there isn't, because `Q_ENUM`'s functionality is implemented in code generated by moc, and moc ignores classes that are neither `Q_OBJECT` nor `Q_GADGET`. There's no reason for not using a `Q_GADGET` since it has no effect on object size: adds no virtual methods nor data fields.

The following demonstrates this:

```
#include <QtCore>

namespace Ns {
class Class {
   Q_GADGET
public:
   enum ESomeEnum {ENUM_A, ENUM_B, ENUM_C};
   Q_ENUM(ESomeEnum)
};
}

int main() {
   auto metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<Ns::Class::ESomeEnum>();
   qDebug() << sizeof(Ns::Class) << metaEnum.valueToKey(Ns::Class::ENUM_A);
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Output:

```
1 ENUM_A
```

On this particular platform (and many others), empty classes are of size 1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since 5.8 you can do:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{ 
Q_NAMESPACE 

enum class MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT MyEnumClass
{
...
}; 

Q_ENUM_NS(MyEnumClass)

...
} // namespace MyLibrary
```

Answer (score 4):

`Q_ENUM` is like the old `Q_ENUMS` but with these differences:

- It needs to be placed after the `enum` in the source code.
- Only one `enum` can be put in the macro.
- It enables `QMetaEnum::fromType<T>()`.
- These `enum`s are automatically declared as a `QMetaType`s (no need to
  add them in `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` anymore).
- `enum`s passed to `qDebug` will print the name of the value rather than
  the number.
- When put in a `QVariant`, `toString()` gives the value name. The value name
  is printed by `QCOMPARE` (since Qt 5.6)

Taken from [WOBOQ blog post on the topic](https://woboq.com/blog/q_enum.html), read it for additional information regarding `Q_ENUM` vs `Q_ENUMS`.